# Why is calling float() on a number slower than adding 0.0 in Python?

Tags: python, casting, floating-point, integer

What is the reason that casting an integer to a float is slower than adding 0.0 to that int in Python?

```
import timeit


def add_simple():
    for i in range(1000):
        a = 1 + 0.0


def cast_simple():
    for i in range(1000):
        a = float(1)


def add_total():
    total = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        total += 1 + 0.0


def cast_total():
    total = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        total += float(1)


print "Add simple timing: %s" % timeit.timeit(add_simple, number=1)
print "Cast simple timing: %s" % timeit.timeit(cast_simple, number=1)
print "Add total timing: %s" % timeit.timeit(add_total, number=1)
print "Cast total timing: %s" % timeit.timeit(cast_total, number=1)
```

The output of which is:

> Add simple timing: 0.0001220703125
>
> Cast simple timing: 0.000469923019409
>
> Add total timing: 0.000164985656738
>
> Cast total timing: 0.00040078163147

Comment: What's the output of `dis.dis`?

Comment: Put it this way, what would you expect to be faster? `a = "100"` or `b = str(100)`?

Comment: @Jeff: your example is something different. It would be more like `float(100)` vs `100.0`, when the question is about `float(100)` vs `100 + 0.0`.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Except that constant folding means that `100 + 0.0` is the same as `100.0`

Comment: @user22490234: The answer you've accepted only tells a small part of the story. It's showing one source of performance differences out of multiple that combine to produce the observed effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use the `dis` module, you can start to see why:

```
In [11]: dis.dis(add_simple)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 29)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 LOAD_CONST               4 (1.0)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_BLOCK
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE

In [12]: dis.dis(cast_simple)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              32 (to 35)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                18 (to 34)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (float)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             25 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             28 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `CALL_FUNCTION`

Function calls in Python are (relatively) slow. As are `.` lookups. Because casting to `float` requires a function call - that's why it's slower.

Comment: Ok so I see the point that function calls are slow, does that mean that you are always better off using '+ 0.0' instead of calling 'float()'?

Comment: From your question - the difference is between  `0.0001220703125` and `0.000469923019409` - for **`1000`** of these operations. That means that you're looking at an extraordinarily *small* cost regardless of which option you chose. If you happen to profile your code and see that you're calling `float(number)` a billion times, and you're trying to make it go faster because that *directly* means more money, then it might be worth using `+ 0.0`, but otherwise the readability problems you'll have trying to remember why you did `+ 0.0` are *far* more expensive than calling the `float()` function.

Comment: This is only showing part of the story. There are 3 major factors contributing to the performance difference: constant folding, built-in lookup, and function call overhead. This answer only mentions function call overhead.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the bytecode for `add_simple`:

```
>>> dis.dis(add_simple)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 29)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 LOAD_CONST               4 (1.0)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_BLOCK
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll see that `0.0` isn't actually anywhere in there. It just loads the constant `1.0` and stores it to `a`. Python computed the result at compile-time, so you're not actually timing the addition.

If you use a variable for `1`, so Python's primitive peephole optimizer can't do the addition at compile-time, adding `0.0` still has a lead:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('float(a)', 'a=1')
0.22538208961486816
>>> timeit.timeit('a+0.0', 'a=1')
0.13347005844116211
```

Calling `float` requires two dict lookups to figure out what `float` is, one in the module's global namespace and one in the built-ins. It also has Python function call overhead, which is more expensive than a C function call.

Adding `0.0` only requires indexing into the function's code object's `co_consts` to load the constant `0.0`, and then calling the C-level `nb_add` functions of the `int` and `float` types to perform the addition. This is a lower amount of overhead overall.

Comment: +1, I knew constant folding would remove the addition, but didn't stop to consider that the addition would still be faster than the `float` call, should you force it to happen.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Python 3 or a recent version of Python 2 (2.5 or higher), it does constant folding at bytecode generation time. This means that `1 + 0.0` is replaced with `1.0` before the code is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the addition can be done in C.  Doing the cast causes a function to be called and then the C lib to kick in.  There's overhead for that function call.

Answer (score 2):

Simply speaking, you aren't casting anything. A type cast tells the compiler to treat the value in a variable as if it had a different type; the same underlying bits are used. Python's `float(1)`, however, constructs a new object in memory distinct from the argument to `float`.

When you add `1 + 0.0`, this simply calls `(1).__add__(0.0)`, and the `__add__` method of the builtin `int` class knows how to deal with `float` objects. No additional objects (aside from the return value) need to be constructed.

Newer versions of Python have an optimizer so that constant expressions like `1 + 0.0` can be replaced at compile time with `1.0`; no functions need to be executed at run-time at all. Replace `1 + 0.0` with `x = 1` (prior to the loop) and `x + 0.0` to force `int.__add__` to be called at runtime to observe the difference. It will be slower than `1 + 0.0`, but still faster than `float(1)`.

Comment: "A type cast tells the compiler to treat the value in a variable as if it had a different type; the same underlying bits are used" - where did you get that idea? It's not like `reinterpret_cast` is the only type of cast around. Most casts in most languages involve changing the representation of the value in memory.